# How to get rid of annoying extra white spaces on the margins when exporting surface plots to pdf?

Tags: matlab

How to get rid of annoying extra white spaces on the margins when exporting surface plots to pdf, in spite of the use of `exportgraphics` already? **I guess the extra white spaces are caused by the use of `view([-25 50])`, which changes the default viewpoint, but this line is required for my application.**

Example code:

```
[X,Y,Z] = peaks;
surf(X, Y, Z);
view([-25 50]);  %%% This line is necessary, but seems resulting in extra white spaces on the margins
exportgraphics(gcf, 'mypdf.pdf');
```

The resultant pdf file containing extra white spaces on the margin:
[image]

Comment: Does it exhibit the same behavior if you export the current axis rather than figure?  Substituting `gca` for `gcf`?

Comment: @GrapefruitIsAwesome Nope, it didn't help. But I found saving as `png` instead of `pdf` did the trick. No ideas about the reason...

Comment: Hopefully that's a workable solution for you.  I always use the png option and boost the file resolution up to get nice looking images.